# How do I prove that the expectation value of the following two random variables converge to zero?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value, stochastic-calculus

> I have given $X_n,Y_n$ two sequences of real valued random variables in the same probability space. I assume that $X_n\Rightarrow X$ in distribution and $|X_n-Y_n|\rightarrow 0$ in probability. In addition $f:\Bbb{R}\rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ is an arbitrary continuous function s.t. there exists a compact subset $K\subset \Bbb{R}$ with $f(x)=0$ for all $x\notin K$. I need to show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \Bbb{E}\left(|f(X_n)-f(Y_n)|\right)=0$.

My idea was the following:

We first remark that $\Bbb{E}\left(|f(X_n)-f(Y_n)|\right)\geq \left|\Bbb{E}\left(f(X_n)-f(Y_n)\right)\right|\geq 0$. On the other hand $$\Bbb{E}\left(|f(X_n)-f(Y_n)|\right)\leq \Bbb{E}(|f(X_n)|+|f(Y_n)|)\stackrel{*}{=}\Bbb{E}(|f(X_n)|)+\Bbb{E}(|f(Y_n)|)$$ where $*$ only holds since $|f(X_n)|, |f(Y_n)|$ is integrable (this follows since $f$ has compact support). Now using that $X_n\Rightarrow X$ we know that $$\Bbb{E}(f(X_n))\rightarrow \Bbb{E}(f(X))$$ but then $$\Bbb{E}\left(|f(X_n)-f(Y_n)|\right)\rightarrow |\Bbb{E}(f(X))|+\Bbb{E}(|f(Y_n)|)$$ Now since $|X_n-Y_n|\rightarrow 0$ in probability we know that $|f(X_n)-f(Y_n)|\rightarrow 0$ in probability. I thought that one could use this to show that maybe $\Bbb{E}(|f(X_n)|)\rightarrow -|\Bbb{E}(f(X))|$ or something similar, because then I would be done.

But I'm not sure if this really works. Could maybe someone first tell me if this is correct what I wrote and then maybe if not what I need to change. If my work holds till some point it would be nice if we could use it and then proceed with the correct way.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will make a weaker assumption on $f$ which is that it is bounded and uniformly continuous. Fix $\epsilon >0$, then there exists $\delta >0$ such that $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq \epsilon$ whenever $|x-y|\leq \delta$.

We have
$$\mathbb{E}|f(X_n) - f(Y_n)| = \mathbb{E}\left[|f(X_n) - f(Y_n)|\mathbf{1}_{\{|X_n-Y_n|\leq \delta\}}\right]+\mathbb{E}\left[|f(X_n) - f(Y_n)|\mathbf{1}_{\{|X_n-Y_n|>\delta\}}\right].$$

Thanks to uniform continuity, the first term is bounded by
$$ \epsilon \,\mathbb{P}(|X_n-Y_n|\leq \delta) \leq \epsilon.$$

For the second term, we use the boundedness of $f$ to get
$$\mathbb{E}\left[|f(X_n) - f(Y_n)|\mathbf{1}_{\{|X_n-Y_n|>\delta\}}\right]\leq 2\lVert f\rVert_{\infty}\, \mathbb{P}(|X_n-Y_n|>\delta) \to 0.$$
(The last convergence is the definition of convergence in probability.)

Thus, taking limsup on both sides, we deduce that for every $\epsilon >0$
$$\limsup_{n\to \infty} \mathbb{E}|f(X_n) - f(Y_n)| \leq \epsilon.$$
Letting $\epsilon \to 0$ yields the result.

Comment: Ah I see but so I can then do a similar proof with the "stronger" assumptions?

Comment: @aprozz I don't quite see how the stronger assumption simplifies the proof, but I could be missing something.